# Хельсинки, Гельсингфорс, Хельсингборг, Хельсингёр

Tags: этимология

Меня очень заинтересовало сходство в названиях трех городов. Один из них - это столица Финляндии, Хельсинки. По-шведски этот город называется Гельсингфорсом (что отразилось, например, в названии улицы в Петербурге - [Гельсингфорсская](http://www.karta-spb.ru/%D1%83%D0%BB.%20%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%203/0)). Но при этом существует еще два города с похожими названиям - Хельсингборг в Швеции и Хельсингёр в Дании. Стоят они друг на против друга через узкий пролив. При этом эти два города (~1000 и 1200 гг. соответственно) были основаны явно гораздо раньше Хельсинки (~1500 г. н. э.).

Не думаю, что совпадение в названиях случайно. Или артефакт перевода названий на русский язык? Прошу помочь разобраться.

Comment: Название улицы - Гельсин**г**форсская.

Comment: Да, спасибо, опечатка. Поправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю точной истории и даже перевода (попробую потом посмотреть), но ничего удивительного в совпадении я не вижу. Шведское название здесь первично, город Хельсинки был основан и "крещен" шведским королем Густавом Вассой в 1520 г., во время шведского господства.

А, ну вот все относительно и прояснилось.

> Хельсинки — Гельсингфорс, столица Финляндии. Город основан в 1550 г под
> швед, названием Helsingfors; основа helsing нередко встречается в сканд.
> топонимии, но смысл ее неясен, fors - швед, водопад . Фин. название
> Хельсинки (Helsinki) образовано от швед.…

(Географический словарь на "академике")

Comment: Короче, краткое содержание предыдущий частей =) Финны ленивые и решили как-то отличиться, поэтому название города, получается, укоротили. Касательно fors - честно говоря, думал, что это скорее аналог fort, крепости. Ну, да, ладно. Касательно части "Хельсин" есть предположение, что оно идет от шведского слова, обозначающего узкий участок. Это подтверждается географией - Хельсингборг и Хельсигёр стоят в узком месте пролива друг напротив друга.

Спасибо за ответ. А ссылочку на академику можете дать?

Comment: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_geo/5320/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: Еще версия. Жителя провинции Hälsingland в Швеции переселились на территорию Южной Финляндии, где в память о своей родине назвали реку Helsingeå, а уже соответственно место водопада был назван Хельсингфорсом, где и основал город король Густав Васа.